# フッターに表示されている「2 次利用にはクレジット表記が必要です」は「二次利用」に直す

Tags: バグ, 完了

「2次利用」ではなく「二次利用」が日本語の表示として正しいので修正をお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

「二次利用」に改正しました。

次回のビルドに適用します。